# Is it possible to combine Ag-Grid Set Filter and Floating Filters

Tags: ag-grid

We have been using enterprise version of ag-Grid and loving. 
Is it possible to have both set filters with floating filter. Currently If we have set filter the floating filter will only show the text what is selected in set filter. 
There is a requirement to have both set filter with virtual list and an option to type in floating filter which will also work like text filter. The similar options are available in Kendo Grid and UI-Grid.

I know its possible to customize. Can someone help me how can i go about it. Please help.

[UI Grid Filter Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/614KR.png)

[Kendo MVC Grid Filter Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiaG8.png)

[Kendo Silverlight Grid Filter Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzfJ3.png)

Comment: can you link a demo of Kendo Grid or UI-Grid showing this feature?

Comment: Hi Jarod Moser, Thanks for replying. I was not able to find any live demo for the grid sample, However I have attached few images what I am expecting AgGrid filter to behave like.

Comment: Looks like you would need to do a [custom filter component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-interface) and basically recreating the set filter and text filter

Comment: Yes, you are right. To achieve it is a combination of Set Filter and Text Filter. However I am unable to build the Dynamic Virtual List for the column items. The example shown has got all static HTML. It will be possible to register the event on the text box but how do we built the list.